# Empresa de envío de correo electrónico transaccional

Tags: email

Estoy revisando algunas empresas de envío de correo electrónico, lo que necesito es enviar correos electrónicos transaccionales mediante una API a la cual le pueda enviar los datos como son: remitente, titulo del correo, copia a, y el body en html y este lo envíe, asegurando que los correos enviados se enviarán a la bandeja de entrada y no a SPAM.

Ya eh usado Emarsys la cual funciona bastante bien. Pero necesito una plataforma mas pequeña ya que en Emarsys me dijeron que trabajan con empresas que tengan mas de 100 000 contactos y empresas retail y yo estoy creando un servicio para empresas pequeñas.

Eh intentado usar campaignmonitor (la cual no recomiendo para anda) pero nos ah robado dinero ya que al día siguiente de contratar el servicio básico ya no nos dejó acceder a la cuenta, tratamos de recuperar la contraseña pero no nos permite y los de soporte nunca contestan y mucho menos se ponen en contacto.

Necesito una plataforma de envió de correos transaccionales mediante API.

Alguna recomendación.

Agradezco el tiempo que se tomen en leer y responder, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: puedes usar gmail y das de alta la cuenta de correo con el nombre de tu empresa, tiene API para varios lenguajes.

Comment: Lo reviso Miguel, gracias por el dato, supongo que también debe tener algún costo y planes verdad?

Comment: para ser negocio el precio es accessible 6 dolares por mes 30 GB de almacenamiento. https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si alguien llega a necesitar este post ayuda mucho

https://metabox.io/free-transactional-email-services/